# React Native - How to download content from an API at the launch screen

Tags: react-native, download, loader

I've developed an app with react native who's getting some content from an API (texts, photo, audio), and the loading of them are too long (about 5sec for 5Mb) so I'm trying to improve that.
I thinked about making a "download screen" at the launching of my app rather than when I need the data, but I'm not sure about it. Does some have an idea of how I can do something proper ?

Comment: You could use [`react-native-splash-screen`](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen). Once your app has loaded, perform your API calls. Once they've been fulfilled you can call `SplashScreen.hide();`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a progressive indicator showing the percentage of loading completed, you can use "react-native-fetch-blob".

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch-blob

Comment: No, i already know how to do that, I want to download the content before, to have very few loading while the user is using the app

Comment: What problem with using the assets folder?

Comment: Assets folder cannot be used if your content is dynamical, a facebook feed for example, with a lot of images from users.

You can easely download all the content and cache it / store it in the app

Comment: @Poptocrack that's what I'm trying to do, how do you download the content and cache it in the app ?

Comment: You should be able to do it with the plugin linked by @ChrisCallwait

Comment: Yes, but I can't find the solution to do it